# How to send sms to selected contacts in android on longpress?

Tags: java, android, listview

Here is a list of contacts in `ListView`, here when user longpress on any contact a context menu appears with an option `send sms` when user press `send sms` option then sms should be send to selected number. here the problem is that phone value is always null while sending sms, i don't know why? Instead of null it should be selected number.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView listView;
Button sync;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
String name, phone;
ArrayList<Contact_list> listitem;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listitem = new ArrayList<Contact_list>();
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewID);
    registerForContextMenu(listView);

    sync = (Button) findViewById(R.id.syncID);
    sync.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // GET CONTACTS DATA
            GetContactsIntoArrayList();
            listView.setAdapter(new Custom_adapter(MainActivity.this, listitem));
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "import", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

public void GetContactsIntoArrayList(){

    //`GetContactsIntoArrayList` is executed here
}

 @Override
 public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
       super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
       menu.setHeaderTitle("Select The Action");
       menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Call");
       menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Send SMS");
}  

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();

    //  info.position will give the index of selected item
    int IndexSelected=info.position;
    if(item.getTitle()=="Call")
    {
        // Code to execute when clicked on This Item
    }
    else if(item.getTitle()=="Send SMS")
    {
        // here phone values is always null why?
        intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse( "sms:" + phone));
        intent.putExtra( "sms_body", "hi" );
        startActivity(intent);
        // Code to execute when clicked on This Item
    }
    else
    {
       return false;
    }
    return true;


 }
```

}

Comment: Is `GetContactsIntoArrayList` ever executed?

Comment: yes `GetContactsIntoArrayList` is executed @Asalle